# Does Android provide auto-switching of network mode when mobile data is toggled?

Tags: settings, mobile-data, system

Whenever I want to turn on the mobile data, I have to go to "Preferred network type" menu and Switch to 3G/4G/Prefer LTE manually which requires many steps.

So does Android OS provide auto switching to 3G/4G/Prefer LTE mode when network turns on and auto switching to 2G mode when I turn off the mobile data?

Note: I'm using MI note 4 mobile with Android 7.0.

If there is no such option, how can I send this as a suggestion to Google or Android developers?

Comment: Nevermind, I just learned about Dual SIM Dual Standby. You should mention that in your post. Switching between Sim1 & Sim2 as preferred and secondary is not the same as switching off mobile data. `there are some exceptions to the rule. Some smartphones, for example, can also connect the secondary SIM card to the internet in DSDS smartphones without using Hot Swap, but the card only supports the old 2G networks, as it does not have physical access to the 3G/4G modem and antenna reserved for the main card` Possible Clandestine wow. That's a protocol thing. Can you provide the primary slot APN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does Android OS provide auto switching to 3G/4G/Prefer LTE mode when network turns on and auto switching to 2G mode when I turn off the mobile data?

**No**, it doesn't

> If there is no such option, how can I send this as a suggestion to Google or Android developers?

Yes. You can, as [mentioned here](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs)

> You can help improve Android by reporting issues and feature requests in the [Android Issue Tracker](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs#bug-queues).

IMO, this would fall in the [Networking](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:192634%2B) section.

I wouldn't cross my fingers hoping something will come out of the bug report but it's your call.

If you root your device and install Xposed framework, you can install [Gravity Box](https://repo.xposed.info/module/com.ceco.oreo.gravitybox) and select *Smart Radio* option (Note: As of today, Xposed framework has not been ported to Pie; Gravity Box module & Xposed framework vary as per Android version). Also, Gravity Box works best on AOSP ROMs so it's better to check out in your device forums if it works well or not.

Using this feature you can switch to 2G when you are not using the data network and switch to selected network automatically when using data. I use it and snapshots below show the choices of network when 
 connected / not connected to data (power saving and normal mode). In addition you can fine tune switching and create a Quick Settings tile for it.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

(Tap to enlarge)